# VS2010 sees bool as unsigned char

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost

When I try to compile a project with Boost references I get a few error C2766:

"explicit specialization; 'boost::is_integral' has already been defined"

It complains with:

```
BOOST_TT_AUX_BOOL_TRAIT_CV_SPEC1(is_integral,bool,true)
```

Saying it was already defined at:

```
BOOST_TT_AUX_BOOL_TRAIT_CV_SPEC1(is_integral,unsigned char,true)
```

All the other error C2766s indicate that the compiler is seeing bools as unsigned chars.  I had nearly an identical issue where I just added a `#ifdef` around the problem spot to fix it, but editing a library's header file is not really a good for having to pass the project on to co-workers:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23573211/error-c2766-explicit-specialization-redefinition-within-windows-header

Any thoughts on why VS2010 is interpreting the bool in that manner?

Comment: Have you checked your header files for something like `#define bool unsigned char`? Try adding `#undef bool` right above the offending line; if that fixes it then you need to hunt down and delete the macro.

Comment: There has to be some header file that you're including that is causing this. You are not alone. I find other similar questions, [like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814638/vc-10-treating-bool-as-char-at-explicit-template-specialization). None of them have enough information provided to track down the issue.

Comment: Are you perhaps including `<stdbool.h>`?

Comment: @Praetorian Found it in a co-worker's header file...weird that it didn't appear in the preprocessor output where I was searching for it a while ago.

Comment: Unfortunately, the follow-up question ("What is the most appropriate punishment for a co-worker who uses macros to redefine fundamental types?") will be off-topic for Stack Overflow. :-(

Comment: SHOOT THEM IN THE FACE AND THEN MURDER THEM WITH AN AXE THEN CUT OFF THE HEAD AND FILL IT WITH GARLIC AND FEED THE HEAD TO SHARKS (THEY LOVE GARLIC) THEN CUT UP THE BODY AND EAT IT AS STEW.

Comment: @CodyGray: Would it be on-topic for Programmers.SE?